For all $n\in\mathbb{N},\ n+1/2$ is in a $3-$term A.P. with two other members of Szekeres's sequence.
Let $A:=$ Szekeres's sequence = $1,2,4,5,10,11,13,14,28,29,31,32,37,38,\ldots$
Due to the greedy construction of this sequence, appending any number not already in the sequence causes it to no longer be $3-$term A.P.-free.
Noting that $2A= 2,4,8,10,20,22,26,28,56,58,\ldots$ is obviously also $3-$term A.P.-free, I considered $2A\cup\{1\} = 1,2,4,8,10,20,22,26,28,56,58,\ldots$ which also obviously avoids $3-$term A.Ps. Obviously we cannot append any even numbers to $2A$ and it remain $3-$term A.P.-free. But then I wondered if we can append odd numbers greedily to $2A\cup\{1\}$ whilst avoiding $3-$term A.Ps and compare it to $A.$ But when I tried this, I noticed that I cannot append any odd numbers to $2A\cup\{1\}$ without creating a $3-$term A.P.* So, my original question was this:

Is $2A\cup\{1\}$ a maximal Salem-Spencer set, in the sense that no integer (not already in the set) can be appended to the set without creating a $3-$term A.P.? If so, why?

But now a slightly broader question is this:

Can any odd number $ \geq 3$ be appended to $2A$ so that this new set remains $3-$term A.P.-free? [This is
equivalent to asking why, for all $n\in\mathbb{N},\ n+1/2$ is in a
$3-$term A.P. with two other members of $A.$] Another way of asking this is: Is $1$ the only number that can be appended to $2A$ so that it remains Salem-Spencer?

*I will update this question in the morning by writing a program which checks for larger numbers. So far, I have only checked by hand, for small (odd) numbers up to $37.$

That's not equivalent right? Because you are looking at $2A \cup {1}$, if the new element uses 1 in the 3-term AP.

@Calvin Lin You are right. I should clarify my question.

Claim: Every number $ n \geq 2$ (not necessarily odd) can be written as the average of 2 (not necessarily distinct) numbers in $2A$.
Proof: Recall the alternative definition, that $a_n - 1$ in ternary is equal to $n-1$ in binary.
Let $B$ be the set of integers whose ternary representation only uses 1 and 0. Then, $ \{ a -1 | a\in A \} = \{  b | b \in B \}$).
We will show that
$2(n-2) = 2(c-1) + 2(d-1)$, where $c-1, d-1 \in A$, or equivalently that $n = c + d$  where $c, d \in B$.
Let $ n = \overline{n_k n_{k-1} \ldots n_0 }_3$.
Define $c_k = \begin{cases} 0 &  n_k = 0, 1\\  1 & n_k = 2 \\ \end{cases}$ and $d_k = \begin{cases} 0 &  n_k = 0\\  1 & n_k = 1, 2 \\ \end{cases}$.
By construction, $c_n + d_n = n_k$ so $c+d = n$, and $c = \overline{c_k c_{k-1} \ldots c_0 }_3 \in B,  d = \overline{d_k d_{k-1} \ldots d_0 }_3 \in B$ as desired.
Note: It is possible that $ c = d$, which implies that $n \in 2A$.
If $ c \neq d$, then $c, n, d$ is a 3-term AP. (Furthermore this requires some $n_i = 1$, and thus $ n \not \in 2A$.)
Corollary: To $2 A$, we cannot append any new ($n \not \in 2A$) number $ n \geq 2$,   without getting a 3-term AP. At best we can add in $ n = 1$, which obviously works. Hence $ 2A \cup \{1 \}$ is a maximal 3-term AP free set.
